# How do I fix 'NotebookApp.allow_origin is Invalid argument' issue?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run a google colaboratory notebook locally. I followed the connection guide provided by jupyter-notebook which lays out the steps to establish connection on the local port.

https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html  provides the steps for establishing connection. I have completed steps 1 & 2 as I already have Jupyter installed. 
Step 3 asks me to execute the following in CMD:

```
    jupyter notebook \
    --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' \
    --port=8888 \
    --NotebookApp.port_retries=0
```

This is where the trouble occurs. I tried executing the below code but failed.

CODE:

```
    jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.allow_origin =      "https://colab.research.google.com" --port = 8888 --NotebookApp.port_retries= 0
```

ERROR:

[C 20:47:43.718 NotebookApp] Bad config encountered during initialization:

[C 20:47:43.718 NotebookApp] Invalid argument: '--NotebookApp.allow_origin'

I tried looking into the jupyter config documentation for this [which is here](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html). 
The documentation also suggested creating a config file called jupyter_notebook_config.py which allows you to set the defaults for these configs. 
I tried setting the default for NotebookApp.allow_origin [image: in this fashion] an then try and run the jupyter notebook by just passing the port and port_retries arguments (assuming the default for allow_origin now served my purpose) and then tried but that did not seem to work as well.

Any suggestions and assistance are most welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the extra whitespace in your command is causing the error; you wrote

```
    jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.allow_origin =      "https://colab.research.google.com" --port = 8888 --NotebookApp.port_retries= 0
```

but you want

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.allow_origin="https://colab.research.google.com" --port=8888 --NotebookApp.port_retries=0
```